# Method of proving trignometric identities

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question

> How do we prove trigonometric identities?

When my teacher did it in school today all I could see was him doing random steps. I didn't really understand his method. I am basically asking whether my process is correct or not. If not what is wrong and how to improve it. I need someone to  me the steps of solving trigonometric identities/ trigonometry method.

From what I have understood:

1. Check expression to see if you can simplify e.g. cancel out
2. Check expression to see if their are any trig identities you can sub in
3. Simply by cancelling out or by using foil or by factoring
4. Check expression to see if their are any trig identities you can sub in?
5. Simply by cancelling out or by using foil or by factoring

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no one universal method for all problems. But there are some guidelines:

$1$: Look at the problem and see if some known trigonometric identities can help. For instance, can we use $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$ somewhere to simplify?

$2$: Make use of some algebraic identities: For instance, $\sin^2(x) - \cos^2(x) = (\sin(x) - \cos(x))(\sin(x) + \cos(x))$, which stems from the fact that $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.

$3$: Look at what you want to prove and simplify accordingly. For instance, if the right hand side is just in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, then expressing all the trigonometric functions on the left hand side as function of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ might be helpful.

The list goes on and on. At the end of the day, you need to pick the right tool to attack the problem. So make sure to possess lot of useful mathematical tools.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all those methods will come into play when you want to prove trig identities. The best thing I would suggest you to do is to find some exercises on proving trig identities and try doing them; practice makes perfect. For example the following sample exam sheet might help you. Try to do them and then check your answers.

http://www.teaching.martahidegkuti.com/shared/lnotes/trigidentities1/trigidentities1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In general, to *prove* an identity, you need to show that the expression on one side is equal to the expression on the other. Using the methods you listed, if you can reduce the two sides to the same expression, then you have proven the identity. If you manipulate the equation to derive something that you know is true, then you have also proven the identity.

---

For example, if you need to prove that $$\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x) = 1 - \frac{\sin^2(2x)}{2}$$

We know that $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, so $$\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x) = 1 - \frac{\left(2\sin(x)\cos(x)\right)^2}{2}$$

$$\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x) = 1 - \frac{4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)}{2}$$

$$\sin^4(x) + \cos^4(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$$

$$\sin^4(x) + 2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) + \cos^4(x) = 1$$

We can factor the left side as:

$$\left(\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)\right)^2 = 1$$

But $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, so this just becomes

$$1^2 = 1$$

$$1=1$$

This is obviously true, so you've proved the identity.